# Poner codigo SQL de otra manera en Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, .net, inyección-sql

Tengo una duda, hace meses trabaje en varios proyectos web, y yo tenia la costumbre de poner siempre el código SQL puro en el manejo de las consultas desde el lenguaje de programación usado, ya sea C# o .NET, y me comentaron que esa es la forma mas insegura de hacer la aplicación por la cuestión de algún ataque que se pueda presentar, entonces recuerdo que existe una manera tanto de conectar hacia la base de datos como hacer las consultas que no expone uno fácilmente el código SQL.

Espero me puedan ayudar, y si necesitan alguna SS de que pudiera ser ya que no veo viable poner de mi código.

Comment: No es del todo precisa esa información. La parte insegura es no utilizar consultas parametrizadas en el código que lanza .NET contra la base de datos, para evitar la inyección sql. Si quieres un plus más, puedes desarrollar el código Sql en la base de datos directamente, y solo recibir parámetros de entrada/salida y la respuesta a la petición. No obstante tú pregunta, sin código, se puede basar en opiniones [sqlParameters](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)

Comment: [Aquí](https://www.mclibre.org/consultar/php/lecciones/php-db-inyeccion-sql.html) puedes leer más acerca de Inyección SQL. Coincido con Javi fer2, Tu pregunta puede ser cerrada porque tal como está, parece basada en opiniones.

Comment: si tienen razón es cuestión de opiniones a como formule mi pregunta, veré cual es la mejor forma de organizar mi proyecto, gracias

Comment: deberias estar usando un orm, dapper es un orm que puedes llevar las consultas a objetos

Comment: @ger Un orm no es una solución completa. Mal utilizado puede ser un problema de rendimiento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existen 2 puntos que pueden ser a los que se refiere tu pregunta.

El primer punto es referente a como se maneja el código SQL dentro del código C# o .NET (o cualquier otro lenguaje similar). Si concatenas cualquier valor ingresado por el usuario (inclusive alguno que se haya ingresado con anterioridad y no en el proceso actual) puedes ser víctima de inyección de SQL. La mejor forma de evitarlo es usando instrucciones preparadas ([Prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)) que básicamente parametrizan los valores y evitan que formen parte de la cadena.

El otro punto es que los servidores web, por lo general tienen un acceso más directo a la red pública y pueden ser los primeros objetivos de ataques o inclusive se puede obtener el código de la aplicación en caso de obtener acceso al mismo.

Ambos puntos pueden ser combatidos mediante el uso de procedimientos almacenados (stored procedures) en la base de datos. Esto permite agregar una capa de seguridad puesto que debería de haber un firewall adicional entre el servidor de base de datos y el servidor web, además de requerir permisos adicionales para ingresar a la base de datos.

Comment: Muchas gracias Luis, optaré por la parte de los procedimientos almacenados donde se hagan las consultas desde el mismo SP y solo se llamen por el puro nombre